# explanation of this example which shows that $(f,\mu)$ ergodic does not imply $(f \times f, \mu \times \mu)$ ergodic

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, ergodic-theory

Can anyone help me to understand this example. I have already proved that irrational rotation is ergodic. This example is showing that $f \times f$ is not ergodic. But I am not understanding what this transformation does not satisfy so that it is not ergodic

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation $(x,y)\mapsto(\theta x,\theta y)$, where $\theta$ is a rotation, leaves the ratio $x^{-1} y$ invariant.

The set of $(\exp(ix),\exp(iy))$ for which (say) $\Re\exp(i(x-y))>0$ is invariant under the translations  $(\exp(ix),\exp(iy))\mapsto(\exp(ix+i\theta),\exp(iy+i\theta))$.  But that set does not have measure zero or full measure.

Said another way: $T$  is ergodic if the only $T$-invariant functions are a.e. constant.  But $(a,b)\mapsto a/b$ is invariant and not constant.

Comment: that's exactly what I do not understand. Why from this conclude that the system is not ergodic?